# ID generator incorporated in fishnet?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, python-script-tool

I am having difficulties completing a python tool.

I am trying to make an ID generator for unique values per grid. This will be a concatenated field of the layer (feature code, XX) + column of the fishnet (XX) + row of the fishnet (XX) + the Nth added feature (XXX)= the ID or 'FACILITYID'(9 digits, XXXXXXXXX)

Picture of the tool:
[image]

Picture of ArcMap
[image]

I.E., For Manholes I am trying to have the Feature Code be 60, and this will be the 106th manhole added into this cell. I would like the script to put the value of 601519106 into the selected NULL.

I keep getting this error.

line 44, in main
    if row.idField in nullvalues:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'idField'

Here is my code so far:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"R:\Staging.gdb"

#Setting Parameters for tool
inputLayer = arcpy.GetParameter(0) #Input layer
i = arcpy.GetParameter(1) # Feature Class Code
idField = 'FACILITYID'
nullvalues = ["", " ", None, 0]
grid = r"R:\Toolbar\Shapefiles\Grids.shp"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(grid, 'grid_lyr')
grid_lyr = 'grid_lyr'
selected_lyr = 'selected_lyr'
field_names = arcpy.UpdateCursor(grid_lyr)
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(inputLayer)

#Select by NULL attribute
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputLayer, 'NEW_SELECTION', '"FACILITYID" is NULL')
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(inputLayer, 'intersect', arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management (grid_lyr, 'intersect', inputLayer))
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(inputLayer, selected_lyr, "relative")
ID = arcpy.GetCount_management('selected_lyr.lyr')
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputLayer, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

for field in field_names:
    C = str(field.getValue('COL'))
    R = str(field.getValue('ROW'))

COL, useless1 = C.split('.')
ROW, useless2 = R.split('.')

#Starting the tool
arcpy.AddMessage("Generating ID's...\n")

FC = str(i).zfill(2)
Col = str(COL).zfill(2)
Row = str(ROW).zfill(2)
Fno = str(ID).zfill(3)
Code = str(FC + Col + Row + Fno)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inputLayer, idField) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row.idField in nullvalues:
            row.FACILITYID = Code
            cursor.updateRow(row)
            row = cursor.next()

del row
arcpy.Delete_management('grid_lyr')
arcpy.Delete_management(selected_lyr)
arcpy.AddMessage("\n\nFinished...")
arcpy.AddMessage("Last ID created: " + Code)
```

Comment: What's the problem? :)

Comment: Hi, when I try to run this, I keep getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'idField'.

Also, the column and row fields are not producing the correct value. Its always the same number, but not the right number.

Comment: People will have a hard time trying to help you without getting enough information. Please add more details, illustration and explaining how you work with the rows and columns. It should be clear and tidy, please.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have mixed the `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()` with the `arcpy.UpdateCursor()` syntax.  Try changing your syntax to match the [`arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()` requirements](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm)

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inputLayer, idField) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in nullvalues:
            row[0] = Code
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

You need to refer to fields as a list index like `row[0]`, and you don't need `row = cursor.next()`

Comment: @user109685 That should be asked as a new question.  Your question here was related to your error message - if my answer has fixed that then this question is answered and any further questions should be asked separately.